# how to convert pd.Series to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My env: python3.6_x64, pandas 0.17.0, numpy 1.12.0

**Code:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df_date = pd.Series(['2017-3-1','2017-3-2'])
>>> df_date
0    2017-3-1
1    2017-3-2
>>> pd.to_datetime(df_date)
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "2017-3-1" at position 5
...
SystemError: <class 'str'> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: I update pandas to 0.19.2 , and same error..

Comment: Works fine on `0.18.1`

Comment: Works perfect in `0.19.2`

Comment: Also works `print (pd.to_datetime(df_date, format='%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: but is possible use `pd.to_datetime(df_date, errors='coerce')` for convert problematic strings to `NaT`

Comment: and check all non convertable values by `print (df_date[pd.to_datetime(df_date, errors='coerce').isnull()])
`

Comment: Dears , what python version do you use ?

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df_date, errors='coerce') 0   NaT
1   NaT   ;;;; print (df_date[pd.to_datetime(df_date, errors='coerce').isnull()]) 0    2017-3-1
1    2017-3-2

Comment: I found this [link](https://bugs.python.org/issue28892) , so I think I should use py3.5

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14561) in `pandas` when using [Python 3.6](https://bugs.python.org/issue28892)  It was marked as fixed in [pandas version `0.19.2`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/whatsnew.html)

```
In [12]: pd.Timestamp('invalid')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "invalid" at position 0 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-91abde127db1> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.Timestamp('invalid')
pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.Timestamp.__new__ (pandas/tslib.c:9932)()
pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:25231)()
pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.convert_str_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:26851)()
pandas/src/datetime.pxd in datetime._string_to_dts (pandas/tslib.c:87106)()
SystemError: <class 'str'> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: still wrong in pandas 0.19.2 , so I use py3.5 now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want a date time column, then consider converting your pandas Series object to a simple DataFrame object and then converting the column to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

My env: pandas (0.18.1),numpy (1.12.1), Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr 18 2017, 01:19:53)

I working same code but have no error.
My output like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df_date = pd.Series(['2017-3-1','2017-3-2'])
>>> pd.to_datetime(df_date)
0   2017-03-01
1   2017-03-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```